# Applicable seismometers data?

Tags: earthquakes

I need to study low frequency range of seismic waves (~ up to 0.07Hz). Is it correct to use accelerometers data to compare with synthetic seismograms. Synthetic seismograms are calculated up to 0.07Hz. I found several explanations, that accelerometers data in mostly for high frequencies? Or should I mostly consider broad-band and long period seismometers for my case?

For example here "senses" of different instruments I found:

[image]